# Missing Push Notification Entitlement

Tags: app-store-connect

When submiting a app fro review I got the following message:

> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include
>   API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the
>   app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service,
>   make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the
>   Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a
>   Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push
>   Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does
>   not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required.
>   You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning.
>   If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the
>   developer for information on removing the API.

But I couldn't find how to remove the Push Notification service in the link that was supplied.

How do I remove Push Notification service from my app?

Answer (score 1):

Apple probably won't reject your app on this basis, they're just letting you know that you're referencing an API that you haven't set up at Apple's end.

You could try removing the following methods from your AppDelegate.m :

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication*)application
    didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification*)notification

- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application
   didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken

- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Comment: I have only one method mentioned here the first one `- (void) application:(UIApplication*)application
    didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification*)notification` because my app needs to show local notification for application. Does this any way be the cause for application rejection or do i need to remove it for removing the warning ?